# Wordpress/WooCommerce - Unique Product Name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to add a unique name to a specific product when it's added to the shopping cart using the woocommerce API?

For example suppose I sell pets. The user decides he wants a dog named spot. He then clicks on a particular dog breed (the product) say border collie and that product should appear in the shopping cart as a border collie named spot.

Comment: Have you tried any code so far?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes. You can change things in your own code by adding filters. So for example, say you want to change the name of the product in the cart. In `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php` there is a filter called 'woocommerce_cart_item_name' where the title is outputted. You can modify this in your own code like so:

```
function your_function( $title, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
     /*code to modify title*/
     return $title;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name','your_function',10,3);
```

You could add this to the `functions.php` of your theme.

How you get the name spot in this function depends on your situation.

Read more about filters at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter